# Zebra EMDK Components folder not visible - Visual Studio 2017

Tags: android, visual-studio, xamarin, motorola-emdk

Im using Visual Studio 2017 Community Edition, i have installed EMDK plugin from Nuget Gallery. When i restarted Visual Studio, it shows the EMDK option in the tool bar (top bar), but when i create a new project, the COMPONENTS folder is not visible.
Appreciate your help.
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there is no EMDK plugin in the Nuget gallery (yet), I'm guessing you mean the EMDK visual Studio add-in.  Did you also install the Xamarin component which is an option available from the toolbar?  http://techdocs.zebra.com/emdk-for-xamarin/2-6/guide/component/install/, that should install the Xamarin component locally on the machine.  Alternatively, you can use one of the existing samples as a template: http://techdocs.zebra.com/emdk-for-xamarin/2-6/samples/

I know Xamarin are moving away from the component store which is probably why the components folder is not visible by default, maybe you will need to install some other Xamarin component from Nuget to get that folder to appear.  The EMDK is moving over to Nuget but that will probably take a few months.

**Update:** as specified in the other answer, the EMDK is now available as a beta from Nuget as detailed on Zebra's site: http://techdocs.zebra.com/emdk-for-xamarin/2-7/guide/nuget/

Comment: Thank you so much. I managed to use the required components from nuget gallery.

Answer (score 2):

It appears they are still in the beta stages of converting the EMDK component to a Nuget package. Luckily they have provided some simple instructions on how to download / add a local Nuget feed in order to reference their package.

http://techdocs.zebra.com/emdk-for-xamarin/2-7/guide/nuget/

**Summary**

1. Download Beta Nuget package (link in article provided above)
2. Create Nuget feed to point to local file system
3. Add EMDK reference to projects